# gRPC and etcd client

Tags: c++, grpc, etcd

This question involves `etcd` specific stuff, but I think the question more related to work with `gRPC` in general.
I'm trying to create `etcd` `Watch` for some keys, since the documentation is sparse I had a look at Nokia [implementation](https://github.com/nokia/etcd-cpp-apiv3)
It was easy to adapt code to my needs and I came up with first version which worked just fine, creating `WatchCreateRequest`, and firing callback on key update. So far so good. Then I've tried to add more than one key to watch. Fiasco! `ClientAsyncReaderWriter` is failing to Read/Write in such a case. Now to the question.

If I have following members in my class

```
Watch::Stub watchStub;
CompletionQueue completionQueue;
ClientContext context;
std::unique_ptr<ClientAsyncReaderWriter<WatchRequest, WatchResponse>> stream;
WatchResponse reply;
```

and I want to support multiple `Watches` added to my class, I guess I have to hold several variables per watch and not as class members.
First of all, I guess, `WatchResponse reply` should be one per `Watch`. I'm less sure about the `stream`, should I hold one per `Watch`? I'm almost sure that `context` could be reused for all `Watches` and 100% sure the `stub` and `completionQueue` can be reused for all `Watches`.
So the question is my guess-work right? Whats about thread safety? Didnt find any documentation describing what objects are safe to use from multiple thread and where I have to synchronize access.
Any link to documentation ([not this one](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/c.html)) will be appreciated!

Test code before I split members into single `Watch` property
(no proper shutdown, I know)

```
using namespace grpc;
class Watcher
{
public:
    using Callback = std::function<void(const std::string&, const std::string&)>;

    Watcher(std::shared_ptr<Channel> channel) : watchStub(channel)
    {
        stream = watchStub.AsyncWatch(&context, &completionQueue, (void*) "create");
        eventPoller = std::thread([this]() { WaitForEvent(); });
    }

    void AddWatch(const std::string& key, Callback callback)
    {
        AddWatch(key, callback, false);
    }

    void AddWatches(const std::string& key, Callback callback)
    {
        AddWatch(key, callback, true);
    }

private:
    void AddWatch(const std::string& key, Callback callback, bool isRecursive)
    {
        auto insertionResult = callbacks.emplace(key, callback);
        if (!insertionResult.second) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Event handle already exist.");
        }
        WatchRequest watch_req;
        WatchCreateRequest watch_create_req;
        watch_create_req.set_key(key);
        if (isRecursive) {
            watch_create_req.set_range_end(key + "\xFF");
        }

        watch_req.mutable_create_request()->CopyFrom(watch_create_req);
        stream->Write(watch_req, (void*) insertionResult.first->first.c_str());

        stream->Read(&reply, (void*) insertionResult.first->first.c_str());
    }

    void WaitForEvent()
    {
        void* got_tag;
        bool ok = false;

        while (completionQueue.Next(&got_tag, &ok)) {
            if (ok == false) {
                break;
            }
            if (got_tag == (void*) "writes done") {
                // Signal shutdown
            }
            else if (got_tag == (void*) "create") {
            }
            else if (got_tag == (void*) "write") {
            }
            else {

                auto tag = std::string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(got_tag));
                auto findIt = callbacks.find(tag);
                if (findIt == callbacks.end()) {
                    throw std::runtime_error("Key \"" + tag + "\"not found");
                }

                if (reply.events_size()) {
                    ParseResponse(findIt->second);
                }
                stream->Read(&reply, got_tag);
            }
        }
    }

    void ParseResponse(Callback& callback)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < reply.events_size(); ++i) {
            auto event = reply.events(i);
            auto key = event.kv().key();
            callback(event.kv().key(), event.kv().value());
        }
    }

    Watch::Stub watchStub;
    CompletionQueue completionQueue;
    ClientContext context;
    std::unique_ptr<ClientAsyncReaderWriter<WatchRequest, WatchResponse>> stream;
    WatchResponse reply;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Callback> callbacks;
    std::thread eventPoller;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry that I'm not very sure about the proper `Watch` design here. It's not very clear to me whether you want to create a gRPC call for each `Watch`.

Anyway, each gRPC call will have its own `ClientContext`, `ClientAsyncReaderWriter`. But `stub` and `CompletionQueue` is not per-call thing.

As far as I know, there is no central place to find the thread-safe classes. You may want to read the API document to have a correct expectation.

When I was writing the [async server load reporting service](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/cpp/server/load_reporter/load_reporter_async_service_impl.cc), the only place I add synchronization myself is around `CompletionQueue`, so that I don't en-queue new tags to the cq if it's shut down.

Comment: Already figured out that `ClientContext` should be per call, they ASSERT on context reuse. What API documentation do you mean? So far, the only "documentation" is the code itself. Which is ok but not always clear enough. I think gRPC deserves a guide in the style ZMQ provides

Comment: I think it's helpful to read the comment above the API before using it. You can also find the API reference [here](https://grpc.io/grpc/cpp/index.html).